# Will TensorFlow 2.0 support common Machine Learning libraries stated below?

Tags: tensorflow

With the exciting new features of TensorFlow 2.0, may I know if TensorFlow 2.0 will still support the common machine learning techniques as stated below?

- **Linear Regression**
- **Logistic Regression**
- **K-Means Clustering**
- **K-Nearest Neighbors**
- **Random Forest**
- **Naive Bayes**
- **Support Vector Machine**

Thank you very much for your time and clarification in advance.

Comment: There are some words about compatibility in [the original announcement](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/bgug1G6a89A), but I don't think you'll get anything more specific before an actual release. `tf.contrib` as such will not exist, and subproject maintainers will be responsible for compatibility ("we will work with the respective owners on detailed migration plans", "we are looking for owners/maintainers for a number of projects currently in tf.contrib"). I'd assume everything officially supported now will be there, but no guarantees about `tf.contrib`.

Answer (score 0):

The models that you mention above will still definitely be supported in TensorFlow 2.0 as part of [`tf.estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/estimator). If you are using a symbol in TensorFlow 1.x that is currently housed in [`tf.contrib`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib), it will either be deprecated, transitioned to the [`tensorflow/addons`](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons) repo, or moved into the core TF 2.0 API.

You can check out the RFCs below for more detailed changes:

- [TensorFlow Namespaces](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180827-api-names.md)
- [Sunsetting `tf.contrib`](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md)
- [Move from `tf.contrib` to `tensorflow/addons`](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20181214-move-to-addons.md)